# I had a flask api . Whoever uses this api i should limit their calls by tracking their ip address using flask and python

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I had an API ,whoever hits this API I should limit their calls **by tracking their IP address**.If one user hits my API for the second time ,I should decrease their calls.They can hit my API from mobile or system whatever it may be.Using flask and python ,Please give me any suggestion or tutorial.Thanks in advance.

I tried this code but I am able to track only their public IP ,I want their local IP  along with public IP.

```
@app.route('/api.text-services/sentiment', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def Demoapi():
     ipaddress=request.remote_addr

Result:106.XX.XX.XX(Public IP)

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
@app.route('/api.text-services/sentiment', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def Demoapi():

    ipaddress=request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', request.remote_addr)
```

Result:106.XX.XX.XX(public IP)

```
@app.route('/api.text-services/sentiment', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def Demoapi():
    ipaddress=origin=request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-For', request.remote_addr)
```

Result:106.XX.XX.XX(public IP)

I expect the result as 106.XX.XX.XX(public IP)_10.0.XX.XXX(local IP) using flask and python.From which system the user hits my API I should be able to track the Public IP and Local IP of that system using flask and python.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is called rate limiting a view. You can rate limit your view using different methods.

1. One that I prefer is using writing a decorator function that will use Redis in the background to keep the count of calls for each client. Check [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/70/) snippet/tutorial from Flask community.
2. The second option is using [Flask-Limitter](https://github.com/alisaifee/flask-limiter) extension, which basically implements the first option as an extension and makes life easy.
3. As a third option, you can implement rate limiting on infrastructure level. If you are going to use Microsoft Azure or AWS for hosting your application, they provide services call Azure API Management and AWS API Gateway, which comes with the feature of rate limiting.

Of course, there are probably other ways to set a call limit on your Flask routes, but these are the most common methods that I have come across so far. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks ,actually I am limiting the calls but I am not able to track both the public IP and local IP address.I am able to track only Public IP address.I want to identify the hits of different users by tracking their IP address.For example: five members  are using the same network but different systems I should know which request came from which system by tracking their both public and private IP address.

Comment: If you are running your application on public internet, rate limiting with IP, is actually wrong. U better consider implementing client API keys and limit based on key. Check Twitter API for example.
Even if you could get the private IP of the user (I believe it is not possible unless you own the network), you would have repeating addresses anyway. Private IP addresses are picked from predefined set of class A, B and C addresses. So it is almost certain that several users would have private IP of 192.168.0.1 or 10.0.0.5.